# Making an automated rig for chemistry test. Cannot read a load cell accurately. Constant drift

Tags: load-cell

I'm making this rig to measure rates of carbonation. It's sensing 6 different variables including mass of sample. The board is Wi-Fi capable (ESP32 WROOM), so I can publish results wirelessly and see what's going on in my browser. Good stuff. HOWEVER, the load cell is killing me.

[image]

I've tried a few things, ending at this setup:

[image]

I've confirmed the input and output resistances of my load cell are identical (995.3Ω) with an LCR meter. I've used Sparkfun's HX711 PCB because I heard the power supply on it is super noise-free. I've made the load cell rig out of aluminum and steel, so it's super stiff. Yet I still see constant drift. Values going down, down, down. Using basic example of the bogde library (link.)

[image]

No idea what to do anymore.

Project is for carbon capture tech.

Comment: Do you see the same drift if you just measure the load cell resistances directly with a good meter? You need to isolate the source of the drift and determine whether it is in the load cell itself or in the electronics.

Comment: You should deliver more information. Manufacturer and model number of the load cell, data sheet, circuit used with load cell? Amplifier and AD converter used for the load cell, voltage source for the load cell?

Comment: Load cell = check your constant current supply, compensate for temperature (or let the cell cool off) if needed.  Usual culprits for drift include drift in supply, loss of adhesion, and heating the cell.

Comment: Let it drift, for hours if necessary, to see if it is a self-heating phenomena.  Plot the range on a chart and see if there is a trend.  Also could it be evaporation of test sample?  Use a metal weight.  Or a maths error somewhere?  You're going to have to try narrowing down the issue and provide some specific and relevant details.

Comment: please do not post pictures of text ... your question is text, so should be the code listing and the captured data

Comment: Have you quantified the actual drift? Ie converted the raw numbers into the weight value? Realise that most of your 24bit resolution will be noise and you’ll be doing good if you get 14 bits of useful resolution. Have you tried turning the loadcell upside down to see if it sag that is causing the drift.

Comment: "drift" is often how high-frequency oscillations look when you sample them too slowly.  You're sampling once per second.  I urge you to closely observe the output that you're sampling with an oscilloscope.

Comment: Are you using a Wheatstone bridge to compensate for temp variations?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik the load cells came without datasheets. I assumed they use Wheatstone bridges. I've ordered a certified load cell as a sanity check. 300g limit.

Comment: @Uwe this is the load cell I'll be working with next week: https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/strain-gauges/4140821. The ones I have right now are cheap wholesale ones. Call me a fool for using them. Very curious if I'll still see the same behaviour with them. This will rule out temperature being the culprit of drift. The HX711 pcb that comes with them is the type I tried first before moving onto the version by Sparkfun with a more noise-free voltage supply: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13879. I plan to continue using this latter PCB with the load cell in my next iteration.

Comment: @jsotola you're right, so sorry.

Comment: @Abel I've got a new certified load cell coming in using a wheatstone bridge. This will rule out temperature causing drift. I can't imagine that power supply or loss of adhesion are the issue here, but I'll cross that bridge once the new load cell arrives.

Comment: That looks EXACTLY like the load cell I used in a recent project.  I fed it through an INA111 instrumentation amp before the ADC and it works great.  Very sensitive and accurate.  How is yours hooked up?  Straight into an ADC?

Comment: I did apply a passive low-pass between the sensor and inst amp:  22k & 470nF

Comment: I would recommend to read the data sheet https://docs.rs-online.com/1a3c/0900766b8010f46a.pdf very carefully and to look for application notes.